# Grails gorm rounding float when saving

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a Domain class with a Float field named hfMonto, and when updating it in the controller using

hfObject.properties=params

Being params:

[image]

When looking at the table, the hfMonto value is rounded up:

[image]

And the version field keeps increasing every time. Setting the hibernate logging to trace shows no errors or warnings.

I'm running Grails 3.3.11 on top of Java 1.8.0_252-8u252-b09-1ubuntu1-b09

Any hints? Thanks

**UPDATE: it only happens with numbers bigger than 1,000,000**

Comment: Does it really round - what does it do if you use `1` e.g.?

Comment: In that case it rounds to zero (and version is incremented too)

Comment: What data type is this in the database?

Comment: float, and the db is 10.4.12-MariaDB-1:10.4.12+maria~bionic

Comment: Could you please create Minimal Reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

I finally made it work by changing the database field to *double* and the Domain attribute to *BigDecimal*.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to check the database field; sometimes the database field (in the actual database) does not match the hibernate field

Make sure that what you are returning from your frontend is what you are expecting; sometimes the frontend returns a 'string' which chops the floating point.

Comment: The field in the db matches - it's float. Regarding what comes from the front, in the debugger screenshot you can see that the parameter that is being sent to the hibernate layer to be commited is correct (hfMonto->1967029).

Comment: Ah... didn't pay attention to the size of the variable. You should be using a DOUBLE.